# AWS Cloudformation how to reboot an created instance and then again install part of script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Here is what I have to do:

- I have to create an instance using EC2 cloudformation template.
- After certain installation of packages, I like to reboot the instance through cloud formation template itself.
- Once the instance is rebooted, I have to complete the execution of the remaining script.

Please suggest me how this could be done.

This is my current template:

---

```
    {
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

  "Description" : "",
  "Parameters": {
    "VPCID": {
      "Description": "The VPC for this  instance",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
    },
    "SubnetID": {
      "Description": "The Subnet for this instance",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id",
    },
    "AllowedCIDR": {
      "Description": "IP address range (in CIDR notation) of the client that will be allowed to connect to the cluster using SSH e.g., 203.0.113.5/32",
      "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "9",
      "MaxLength": "18",
      "Default": "10.0.0.0/16",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x"
    },
    "SSHKeyName": {
      "Description": "The EC2 Key Pair to allow SSH access to the instance",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
    },
    "TypeOfInstance": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "t2.medium",
      "Description": "Enter t2.medium, t2.large, m3.large, m4.large, m4.xlarge, etc.",
      "ConstraintDescription": "Must be a valid EC2 instance type."
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "Ec2Instance": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "SecurityGroupIds": [
          {
            "Ref": "InstanceSecurityGroup"
          }
        ],
        "KeyName": {
          "Ref": "SSHKeyName"
        },
        "ImageId": "ami-a8d369c0",
        "SubnetId": { "Ref": "SubnetID" },
        "InstanceType": { "Ref": "TypeOfInstance" },
        "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
          "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
          "touch /tmp/testfile\n",
          "yum -y install rng-tools\n",
          "systemctl start rngd\n",
          "systemctl enable rngd\n",
          "yum update -y \n",

          "echo \"################### Install Packages #######################\"\n",


          "reboot \n",


          "echo \"################### Install Remaining packages and configuration #######################\"\n",

        ]]}}
    },
    "InstanceSecurityGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "Enable SSH access via port 22",
        "VpcId" : {
          "Ref" : "VPCID"
        },
        "GroupName": "my-securitygroup",
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [
          {
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "FromPort": "22",
            "ToPort": "22",
            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/148341/linux-schedule-command-to-run-once-after-reboot-runonce-equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no way for cloudformation to trigger mid-way of user-data script after the instance has stopped and then restarted, here is one workaround that I can think of.

Save some kind of flag on the instance just before reboot (example cfn-userdata-script-continue). Download the remaining part of your script to the instance and save it to a pre-defined location

After reboot, check the existence of this flag. If the flag exists, navigate to the location where you saved the partial script. Run the script. Delete the flag cfn-userdata-script

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a scheduled tasks in EC2 instance to complete the tasks. E.g. in windows you can set the tasks to be run once after the reboot.